# java TreeSet - don't remove duplicate items

Tags: java, comparator, treeset

TreeSet removes different items with the same Comprator value. I don't want it be removed.
Is there any way to control this? Or use another container class?

Added:
OK. It seems I can't use Set.
I need insert sorting feature, for performance consideration. Can List do this? Thanks all.

Comment: Use a Comparator which doesn't return 0.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Other than for object that are, in some sense, identical.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin, agreed, You could return 0 when the objects are `==` otherwise compare the `System.identityHashCode()` or just return an arbitrary `1` for objects which have the same content but are not the same object.

Comment: @Petery Lawrey `System.identityHashCode` is not unique. So you'd still need a tie-breaker (perhaps using `WeakReference`s).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A set by definition can not have duplicate entries.

So you need to use a List or Array or such

Answer (score 6):

Even it is a set, this is still confusing because the objects are different. For example, a `Set<E>` of different objects `E` will drop some objects when converted to a `TreeSet<E>` based on the `Comparator<E>` used. In both cases, it is a set, but the set of elements stored will be different. In my opinion this is not clarified well in the docs.

A simple solution, if you can change the Comparator, let it not return 0. For example instead of:

```
public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
    return o1.compareTo(o2);
}
```

Use:

```
public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
    return o1 < o2 ? -1: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A main purpose of a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is to *not* have duplicates.
You either don't want a `Set` or you need a different `Comparator`.

Answer (score 3):

A quote from [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) for Set:

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements

Use any derivative of [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Comment: Thanks.But, is there any List derivative that support sorting when item is inserted?

Comment: You can always sort a list using Collections.sort(...) and your original comparator. Alternitavely, you can use 2 sets, one with elements and another with their appearence count i.e. kind of multiset

Comment: Try PriorityQueue from here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html or MinMaxPriorityQueue from here http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MinMaxPriorityQueue.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want a SortedList you can for example take a list and manually call Collections.sort() after each insert.

Or you wrap e.g. an ArrayList to ensure the sort-calls for you:

```
    class SortedArrayList extends ArrayList<String> {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void add(int index, String element) {
        super.add(index, element);
        Collections.sort(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(String element) {
        boolean returnValue = super.add(element);
        Collections.sort(this);
        return returnValue;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends String> c) {
        boolean returnValue = super.addAll(c);
        Collections.sort(this);
        return returnValue;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends String> c) {
        boolean returnValue = super.addAll(index, c);
        Collections.sort(this);
        return returnValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String set(int index, String element) {
        String returnValue = super.set(index, element);
        Collections.sort(this);
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

I hope I got all functions which can require sorting. (Remove is not necessary to override)